# locate file loaded on respond_with @jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my project I have

```
respond_to :json
load_and_authorize_resource

def show
  respond_with @job_pattern
end
```

as per tutorial here http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/
it works like this: when a request comes, for example with format xml, it will first search for a template at users/index.xml

so I checked for job_patterns/index.json but didnt find any file with this name

can anyone guide me where i can find the file or how the output is generated here if it is not with the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `respond_to :json` does not render a view, rather it calls `render json: @job_pattern`.

`render json:@job_pattern` calls `@job_pattern.to_json` and sets the JSON string as the response body. You can do the same with XML or YML.

This is an example of the rails convention over configuration philosophy - if there is a `show.json.[erb|haml]` it takes priority. Otherwise rails will look for an instance variable which corresponds with the name of the controller (`@job` or `@jobs` for index) and attempt to serialize it as JSON.

Further reading:

- [Justin Weiss: `respond_to` Without All the Pain](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/11/03/respond-to-without-all-the-pain/)
- [Rails Guides: Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, your action is `show` so the template associated with is `show.json` in `views/[namespace]/show.json`.

You should create this template, or if this template is not found Rails will automatically invoke [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) on the object passed to `respond_with`.

Refer to [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data).

Answer (score 0):

Recents version of Rails with generated scaffold use show.json.jbuilder as template file.
For more info about it:
[jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)